# Shopware Mail Archive pending status

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have installed https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshPlatformMailArchive in a Shopware 6 Store and recently I have noticed a weird behaviour:

Some emails have the state "pending" and were not sent. System logs do not show any signs of an error. The emails are not being sent until the user clicks "Resend Mail".

This issue only occurs on certain mails.

What does the status "pending" mean? Has anyone encountered this Issue? Is there any way to debug this?